# POST request going through before having post validation

Tags: backend, sveltekit, supabase

I'm using Sveltekit as the framework paired with supabase and have installed a sveltekit form validator. Im pretty new to back end stuff and have just crammed code that I've read online trying tp figure this out. As per title, I have an action that sends signUp auth to supabase and also a form validation.

```js
export const actions: Actions = {
  new: async ({ request, url, locals: { supabase } }) => {
    const formData = await request.formData()
    const email = formData.get('email')
    const password = formData.get('password')
    const confirmPassword = formData.get('confirmPassword')
    const form = await superValidate(request, schema);
    console.log('POST', form)

    const { error } = await supabase.auth.signUp({
      email,
      password,
      options: {
        emailRedirectTo: `${url.origin}/member/auth/callback?next=/member/signIn`,
      },
    })

    if (error) {
      return fail(500, { message: 'Server error. Try again later.', success: false, email })
    }

    if (!form.valid) {
      // Again, return { form } and things will just work.
      return fail(400, { form });
    }

    if (password !== confirmPassword){
      throw error(400, { message: 'Passwords do not match', success: false, email })
    }


  },
};
```

I've been tackling this back end stuff for a while now and I'm burnt out. Any help and suggestions would be greatly appreciated